# javascript/nodejs - how to manipulate Json Object by language

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am using nodejs for the server.

Currently I have a Json in my project folder.

name.json

```
{
  "name_English": "Apple",
  "name_German": "Apfel",
  "name_French": "Pomme"
}
```

When I send request to server, it returns:

`GET http://localhost:3030/name`

```
{
  "name_English": "Apple",
  "name_German": "Apfel",
  "name_French": "Pomme"
}
```

But I found it is not convenient for frontend development.

Is there any way to do something like below?

`GET http://localhost:3030/name?lang=en`

```
{
  "name": "Apple"
}
```

`GET http://localhost:3030/name?lang=fr`

```
{
  "name": "Apfel"
}
```

**Edit 1**
The code of getting the Json in Feathers.js

name.class.js

```
const nameLists = require('../name.json')

exports.Test = class Test {
  constructor (options) {
    this.options = options || {};
  }

  async find (params) {
    return nameLists
  }

};
```

**Edit 2**

Is it possible to make name.json like this?

```
{
  "name": ${name}
}
```

**Edit 3**

The reason I want to achieve above because I have to return whole Json file.
For the internationalization library, it seems needed to handle outside the JSON and I don't know what is the best practise to do so.

Comment: Yes. What server are you using? Express?

Comment: @Will Walsh I am using `Feathers` which is `Express` based, so I think it's the same

Comment: Can you post the code of the GET route?

Comment: @Will Walsh please see Edit 1 above

Comment: I'm going to assume that if you specify `lang=fr` that you should get `Pomme` not `Apfel`.  (likely that was just a typo in your question.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full demonstration with just *express*. (Hope that's ok.)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3030;

const nameLists = require('./name.json');

const unabbreviateLanguage = {
  en: 'English',
  de: 'German',
  fr: 'French'
}

function filterByLanguage(obj, abbr) {
  let language = unabbreviateLanguage[abbr];
  let suffix = '_' + language;
  let result = {};
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (key.endsWith(suffix)) {
      let newkey = key.slice(0, -suffix.length);
      result[newkey] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

app.get('/name', (req, res) => {
  res.json(filterByLanguage(nameLists, req.query.lang));
});

app.listen(port);
```

e.g.:

```
curl http://localhost:3030/name?lang=de
```

output:

```
{"name":"Apfel"}
```

The idea is to iterate over the keys of the input object and prepare an output object that only has keys that match the language suffix (then strip off that suffix).  You'll likely want to either have a mapping of `en` -> `English`, or just use the key names that match the parameter e.g., rename `name_English` to `name_en`.

Answer (score 0):

In FeathersJS, the `params` object of `find` will store the query string of the passed in URL. So if you call `http://localhost:3030/name?lang=en`, the `params` object will be :-

```
{
  query: {
    lang: 'en'
  }
}
```

You can then use this information to determine which result from the JSON to return.

https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/services.html#service-methods

Comment: please see my Edit 2

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do there. In a JSON file, there are no variables to refer to using `${}`.

Comment: please check Edit 3

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to be two parts: handling queries, and handling the internationalization.

Handling the query:

Feathers presents queries through the context object at the following location:

```
context.params.query
```

Handling Internationalization:

There are many solid packages available for handling internationalization:

https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-nodejs-internationalization-libraries?orderBy=RECOMMENDED&

Comment: please see my Edit 2

Comment: @CCCC Already answered before your edit, see my "Handling Internationalization" comment, many packages do basically exactly what youre asking. You set a definitions file for each language and use the variables in your templates, the package handles the rest.

Comment: please check Edit 3